# modify a file using sed or awk

Tags: awk, sed

I have playlist such as bellow:

```
>#EXTM3U
>#EXTINF:654,filenameSong1.aiff
>/Users/myname/Music/folder1/filenameSong1.aiff
>#EXTINF:198,filenamesong2.mp4
>/Users/myname/Music/folder1/subfolder2/filenameSong2.mp4
>#EXTINF:217,filenameSong3.mp3
>/Users/myname/Music/folder1/subfolder3/filenameSong3.mp3
>#EXTINF:341,filenameSong4.mp4
>/Users/myname/Music/folder1/subfolder3/filenameSong4.mp4
```

I would like to change this file using sed or awk or combination of the two

such that filenameSong remains but roots become "/MUSIC/
 e.g.

> /Users/myname/Music/folder1/subfolder3/filenameSong4.mp4 becomes
>   /MUSIC/filenameSong4.mp4
>   or
>   /MUSIC/NEWFOLDERNAME/filenameSong4.mp4

with option to add a new folder name after MUSIC folder.
I think If I could find a way to change replace term in Sed command or/and using basename command for each line.

could someone help me How I could do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the '>' characters in your example text are actual text and not some artifact of formatting:

```
sed 's@^>/Users.*/@>/MUSIC/@' input
```

If you want an option for a subdirectory:

```
#!/bin/sh 

sed "s@^>/Users.*/@>/MUSIC${1+/}$1/@" input
```

Comment: thanks for reply. I am newcomer here. I thought I needed to put ">" in order to block the my code. my script does not contain any ">"

Comment: Thank you I removed only ">" from your code and did exactly what I wanted. Assuming I can add a variable or name of the new folder   name after MUSIC and will be able to add optional new folder name.

Comment: oops: when I run sed "s@^/Users.*/@/MUSIC/"$NewFolderName"${1+/}$1/@" "$1"

Comment: please disregard last comment. I am new here did not know how to delete it.

Comment: in the above file how can I run awk on it skipping the lines that contains "#EXTM3U" and "#EXTINF"? resulting a file without a lines that has "#EXTM3U" and "#EXTINF".

Comment: Not sure I understand the question.  If you want to use the sed solution and not apply the substitution to lines that match "#EXTM3U", do `sed "/#EXTM3U/!s@/Users...."`.  If you want to post process and completely delete lines that match: ` ... | sed '/#EXTM3U/d'`, if you want to use awk: `...| awk '!/#EXTM3U' .  There are many ways to delete a line or to skip it for a particular filter.